# Nested linear-layout weights is it bad for one vertical and one horizontal

Tags: android, performance, android-linearlayout

I have had a read of many of the questions about nested weights being bad for performance.

However Is this only the case where the nested weights are of the same direction?

For example in the views i'm working with I have a lot of vertical weights on a page none of which are nested. However the last one of these vertical layouts has a weight sum and horizontal layout.

So the question:

Is it bad to have nested weights if one is vertical and one is Horizontal. Or would these calculations not affect each other as one is width and one is height?

And If yes Is it as bad as the case where we have nested weights of vertical inside of vertical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, unless you have a *lot* of weighted components, the actual performance hit is negligible.

However, it shouldn't matter which way they're oriented. When a view is sized, it will remeasure each child in both directions. There's only a method to `measure`, which does both width and height at the same time.

Comment: Thanks ill try find the documentation on measure and determine if this agrees with your answer. If so ill mark your reply as the answer.